# Loopback: Applying where filter on Array type field Postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, loopbackjs

I have a model with property:

```
“keys”: {
  “type”: [“string”]
}
```

It stores the data in the column “keys” like so:

row1: [“key1”]

row2: [“key2”]

I am trying to apply filter `{where:{keys: “key1”}}`

This doesn’t return any result using loopback-connector-postgresql (v3.9.1 and v5.0.1).

However same filter is working with loopback-mongodb-connector

Env: Nodejs v10.19.0

Comment: To my knowledge, array filtering is not supported.